# How to change PWA workbox cache strategy in Create-React-App 2

Tags: create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Create-react-app v2 uses the workbox cacheFirst strategy. I want to use staleWhileRevalidate. How can I create a custom service worker and add it too a exising app?

Answer (score 0):

Please update to `create-react-app` v4 if you'd like more control over your service worker.

You can start a new project that will use a service worker that you can make changes to using:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

There are details in the [current documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/).